# Check if a row exists in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to check if a row exists in dataframe, following is my code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('dbo.Access_Stat_all.csv',error_bad_lines=False, usecols=['Name','Format','Resource_ID','Number'])
df1 = df[df['Resource_ID'] == 30957]
df1 = df1[['Format','Name','Number']]
df1 = df1.groupby(['Format','Name'], as_index=True).last()
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.0f}'.format
df1 = df1.unstack()
df1.columns = df1.columns.droplevel()
if 'entry' in df1:
    df2 = df1[1:4].sum(axis=0)
else:
    df2 = df1[0:3].sum(axis=0)
df2.name = 'sum'
df2 = df1.append(df2)
print(df2)
```

This is the output:

```
Name    Apr 2013  Apr 2014  Apr 2015  Apr 2016  Apr 2017  Aug 2010  Aug 2013  
Format                                                                         

entry          0         0         0         1         4         1         0   
pdf           13        12         4        23         7         1         9   
sum           13        12         4        24        11         2         9
```

Does  **if 'entry' in df2:**  only check if 'entry' exists as a column? It must be the case, I guess. We can see that the row 'entry' exists but we still land in the else condition(if it had landed in if the statement sum for Apr 2016 would be 23).

If I check it for the file which don't have the row 'entry', it again lands in else statement(as I expect), so I assume it always enters the else condition.

How do I check if a row exists in pandas?

Comment: `'entry' in df.index` or `df.index.contains('entry')`?

Comment: Thanks, this is what I needed to do

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think you need compare index values - output is `True` and `False` numpy array.
And for scalar need `any` - check at least one `True` or `all` for check if all values are `True`s:

```
(df.index == 'entry').any()

(df.index == 'entry').all()
```

Another solution from comment of [John Galt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45636382/check-if-a-rows-exists-in-pandas/45636557#comment78231917_45636382):

```
'entry' in df.index
```

If need check substring:

```
df.index.str.contains('en').any()
```

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Apr 2013':[1,2,3]}, index=['entry','pdf','sum'])
print(df)
       Apr 2013
entry         1
pdf           2
sum           3

print (df.index == 'entry')
[ True False False]

print ((df.index == 'entry').any())
True
print ((df.index == 'entry').all())
False
```

---

```
#check columns values
print ('entry' in df)
False
#same as explicitely call columns (better readability)
print ('entry' in df.columns)
False
#check index values
print ('entry' in df.index)
True
#check columns values
print ('Apr 2013' in df)
True
#check columns values
print ('Apr 2013' in df.columns)
True

df = pd.DataFrame({'Apr 2013':[1,2,3]}, index=['entry','entry','entry'])
print(df)
       Apr 2013
entry         1
entry         2
entry         3

print (df.index == 'entry')
[ True  True  True]

print ((df.index == 'entry').any())
True
print ((df.index == 'entry').all())
True
```

Comment: This is how you answer a question in my opinion (with examples that is) +1

Comment: @AntonvBR - Thank you.

Comment: One small thing though, another interesting fact that you "left out" is that pandas is build upon numpy, if you can say that, and that is why we can do these comparisons, e.g.**df.index == "entry"** which in fact is a numpy.ndarray.

Comment: @AntonvBR - But how to write it the best to my answer? Can you edit my answer with this information, if have some time ?(my English not so nice). thank you.

Comment: your answer is good as it is. Just pointing it out. In the best of worlds we would link answers to documentation where you can read more and get more insight, don't you agree?

Comment: yes, I agree. But not sure if nice explained this topic in pandas doc, numpy doc in unknown fot me ...

Comment: Let's just leave it as it is! See you around.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to check if a row/line exists in dataframe is using df.loc:

subDataFrame = dataFrame.loc[dataFrame[columnName] == value]

This code checks every 'value' in a given line(separated by comma),
return True/False if a line exists in the dataframe

There is a short example using Stocks for the dataframe

```
# *****     Code for 'Check if a line exists in dataframe' using Pandas     *****

# Checks if value can be converted to a number
# Return: True/False
def isfloat(value):
  try:
    float(value)
    return True
  except:
    return False


# Example:
# list1 = ['D','C','B','A']
# list2 = ['OK','Good','82','Great']
# mergedList = [['D','OK'],['C','Good'],['B',82],['A','Great']
def getMergedListFromTwoLists(list1, list2):
    mergedList = []
    numOfColumns = min(len(list1), len(list2))
    for col in range(0, numOfColumns):
        val1 = list1[col]
        val2 = list2[col]

        # In the dataframe value stored as a number
        if isfloat(val2):
            val2 = float(val2)
        mergedList.append([val1, val2])

    return mergedList


# Returns only rows that have valuesAsArray[1] in the valuesAsArray[0]
# Example: valuesAsArray = ['Symbol','AAPL'], returns rows with 'AAPL'
def getSubDataFrame(dataFrame, valuesAsArray):
    subDataFrame = dataFrame.loc[dataFrame[valuesAsArray[0]] == valuesAsArray[1]]
    return subDataFrame




def createDataFrameAsExample():
    import pandas as pd
    data = {
        'MarketCenter': ['T', 'T', 'T', 'T'],
        'Symbol': ['AAPL', 'FB', 'AAPL', 'FB'],
        'Date': [20190101, 20190102, 20190201, 20190301],
        'Time': ['08:00:00', '08:00:00', '09:00:00', '09:00:00'],
        'ShortType': ['S', 'S', 'S', 'S'],
        'Size': [10, 10, 20, 30],
        'Price': [100, 100, 300, 200]
    }
    dfHeadLineAsArray = ['MarketCenter', 'Symbol', 'Date', 'Time', 'ShortType', 'Size','Price']
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=dfHeadLineAsArray)
    return df



def adapterCheckIfLineExistsInDataFrame(originalDataFrame, headlineAsArray, line):
    dfHeadLineAsArray = headlineAsArray
    # Line example: 'T,AAPL,20190101,08:00:00,S,10,100'
    lineAsArray = line.split(',')

    valuesAsArray = getMergedListFromTwoLists(dfHeadLineAsArray, lineAsArray)
    return checkIfLineExistsInDataFrame(originalDataFrame, valuesAsArray)



def checkIfLineExistsInDataFrame(originalDataFrame,  valuesAsArray):

    if not originalDataFrame.empty:


        subDateFrame = originalDataFrame
        for value in valuesAsArray:
            if subDateFrame.empty:
                return False
            subDateFrame = getSubDataFrame(subDateFrame, value)

        if subDateFrame.empty:
            False
        else:
            return True
    return False


def testExample():
    dataFrame = createDataFrameAsExample()
    dfHeadLineAsArray = ['MarketCenter', 'Symbol', 'Date', 'Time', 'ShortType', 'Size','Price']

    # Three made up lines (not in df)
    lineToCheck1 = 'T,FB,20190102,13:00:00,S,10,100'
    lineToCheck2 = 'T,FB,20190102,08:00:00,S,60,100'
    lineToCheck3 = 'T,FB,20190102,08:00:00,S,10,150'

    # This line exists in the dataframe
    lineToCheck4 = 'T,FB,20190102,08:00:00,S,10,100'

    lineExists1 = adapterCheckIfLineExistsInDataFrame(dataFrame,dfHeadLineAsArray,lineToCheck1)
    lineExists2 = adapterCheckIfLineExistsInDataFrame(dataFrame,dfHeadLineAsArray,lineToCheck2)
    lineExists3 = adapterCheckIfLineExistsInDataFrame(dataFrame,dfHeadLineAsArray,lineToCheck3)
    lineExists4 = adapterCheckIfLineExistsInDataFrame(dataFrame,dfHeadLineAsArray,lineToCheck4)

    expected = 'False False False True'
    print('Expected:',expected)
    print('Method:',lineExists1,lineExists2,lineExists3,lineExists4)



testExample()
```

Click to see the dataframe
[Dataframe from Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGf3R.png)

Comment: Given the rather isolated aspect that you want to show case with your example, it's *not really* short.